# forge keeps crashing on startup

Tags: minecraft-forge

I started up minecraft forge and it crashed. So I went back to the launcher, minecraft is working fine in vanilla, but it won't launch forge.

I've tried going into the files to see if there was a problem, but I didn't find any. I've tried downloading a newer version of forge, but it didn't work either. I've tried the same with java, no success.

I'm using minecraft forge version 1.15.2.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Comment: From Review: Please avoid informal terms, and do not ask people to send anything to your email address. Please read this rules to understand how Stack Overflow works. [How to ask in S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow is not the place for support, you should head over to the [MinecraftForge forums](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/) where they have a specific place for [support](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/forum/18-support-bug-reports/).